# xmlhttprequests work in console, but not in script

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue where I need to retrieve the contents of an XML file and then populate it into a dropdown box. This should be easy, however the link to this XML file changes on a normal basis.

My workaround for this, is to get the page where you download the xml file, find the link, and then use that link for getting the xml file. AKA This will take 2 Http requests.

My code is:

```
var data = null;
var Doc = new Document();
var element;
var link = "";
var xmlDoc;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4 && link === "") {  //if we havent gotten the link yet, get it
        Doc = this.response; //get the HTML document where the link is
        element = Doc.getElementsByClassName("failoverLink")[0];  //get the element with the link
        link = element.href; //get the link
        console.log(link); // IMPORTANT: when running the script, this actually returns the link in this context
    }
    else
    {
        if(this.readyState === 4) //now get the actual XML Document
        {
            xmlDoc = this.responseXML; //get the document
            var txt = "<option></option>"; //construct the dropdown box
            var i;
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Region"); //get all elements that we need for the dropdown
            for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
                txt += "<option>" + x[i].attributes.Name.value + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML = txt; //insert it into the page
        }
    }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/<link 1 of the parent document> replaced for privacy purposes");
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.send(data);
xhr.abort();

var newlink = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + link;
xhr.open("GET", newlink);
xhr.responseType = "document";
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
xhr.send(data);
xhr.abort();
```

The expected result is to actually get the XML Document. This works in the developer console just fine!

When trying to run the actual script though, it shows the link in the console just fine, but outside of the context of the event listener function, it is still null.

Anybody have any ideas?

CORRECTION: Whenever I run each command one by one in the console. It works. Whenever I run them all together, it says it is null. I'm guessing I have to somehow wait until it finishes? If so how?

Comment: You are using the same XMLHttpRequest for two different requests. That is wrong

Comment: How so? Last time I checked that was best practices. And before I changed my code and tried this, I was using two different XMLHttpRequest objects. I still got the same issue.

Comment: Why are you calling `xhr.abort();`???

Comment: Well I called it the first time so it closes the connection before trying to hit the second connection. The second time I called that for consistency.

Comment: but you are aborting it before the calls are complete.

Comment: So how do I wait for the first call to complete then?

Comment: And the second one*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing my own issue. The problem was, that the event listener wasnt finishing the first time before the second call. Here is what I did to fix it.

```
xhr1.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(xhr1.readyState === 4) {
        Doc = xhr1.response;
        element = Doc.getElementsByClassName("failoverLink")[0];
        link = element.href;
        console.log(link);

        xhr2.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4)
            {
                xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                var txt = "<option></option>";
                var i;
                var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Region");
                for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
                    txt += "<option>" + x[i].attributes.Name.value + "</option>";
                }
                document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML = txt;
            }
        });

        var newlink = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + link;
        xhr2.open("GET", newlink);
        xhr2.responseType = "document";
        xhr2.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        xhr2.send(data);
    }
});
```

Yes I did end up having to create two different XHR objects... but I guess it will do.